# android eclipse updated and now app crashes when it trys to run

Tags: android, eclipse

My app was working and I did not change a single thing in the source code.
Eclipse updated and now when I try to run the app it doesn't open and that error messages shows up where you have to force close it.  It doesn't even have the other option of wait like I have seen before.

I know this is very little information but that is all I have and that is why I am so frustrated.  I reverted back ... I reinstalled eclipse and the android plugin.  I tested Hello World and that worked fine.  I am so lost.  This really sucks.  Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have third-party JARs in your project, then I experienced the same thing this morning. You can verify this (poor choice of words, I know) if your LogCat shows a `VerifyError` with no helpful information as the cause of the problem.

The solution that worked for me was to check these items in Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export.

[image: abc]

If this doesn't help, can you post the LogCat output?

Comment: Wow thanks that worked.  I just clicked all the jars like that except the Android x.x version one.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: Happy to help! I hate to pander, but can you accept the answer so (among other things...) the question no longer shows up as unsolved?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue whether I have 3rd party JARs or not. As sastraxi says, when this is a result of a 3rd party JAR, fixing the build path often fixes things. I often find the most effective solution, however, is to click Project -> Clean. This realigns all resources and rebuilds the project according to whatever the new SDK's rules.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic